# set background position with auto

Tags: javascript, css

How to apply and getback the background-size using plain javascript?

I tried:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.style.backgroundPosition = '40px 50px';
console.log(element.style.backgroundPosition);
// logs correct

element.style.backgroundPosition = '40px auto';
console.log(element.style.backgroundPosition);
// logs empty, expected '40px auto'
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTk4A/)

Comment: You ask about background size, but your javascript is looking at background position. Which do you want?

Comment: @cale_b, thanks sorry, fixed. I mean position.

Comment: @ManofSnow, the second code should log `'40px auto'`instead of empty

Comment: The problem is that **auto** is not a valid background position setting.  You can set it to px, %, left, center, right, top, bottom, or inherit - but not auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property css `background-position` not support this syntaxes.

Documentation [W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position)

Maybe the solution is :

```
element.style.backgroundPosition = '40px 0%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, background-position doesn't support `auto`.  I suspect, however, that you are looking for it to center - so what I believe you are looking for is this:

```
element.style.backgroundPosition = '40px center';
console.log(element.style.backgroundPosition);
// logs "40px center"
```